# Android add row to ListView with custom adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

Having a bit of problems with android.
Si heres whats going on, I have a ListView with a custom adapter, what iam tring to do is add rows dynamicly, heres the code:

Adapter:

```
public class ProductAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product>{

    Context context; 
    int layoutResourceId;    
    String data[] = null;

    public ProductAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,String[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data=data;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ProductHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new ProductHolder();
            holder.nameText = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
            holder.quantityText = (EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.quan_text);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ProductHolder)row.getTag();
        }


        Product product = DBAdaptor.getProductByName(data[position]);
        holder.img=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        holder.nameText.setText(product.getName());
        holder.quantityText.setText(" ");

        return row;
    }



    static class ProductHolder
    {
        ImageView img;
        TextView nameText;
        EditText quantityText;
    }
}
```

Here's My Main Activity:

```
public class Main extends Activity
{
    public ListView lstView;
    ProductAdapter productListAdapter;
    DBAdaptor mDb;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);
        openDB();
        productListAdapter = new ProductAdapter(this,        R.layout.shoping_list_row,getAllProducts());
        Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        if(b!=null)
        {
            Product p =(Product) b.getSerializable("Product");
            productListAdapter.add(p);
            productListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


    }


}
```

Theres no error coming up but nothing is been add'd to the listView

Kind Reggards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ArrayAdapter relies heavily on its own private Array. You should pass `data` in the appropriate super constructor:

```
super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
```

Then you need to change this line:

```
Product product = DBAdaptor.getProductByName(data[position]);
```

To:

```
Product product = DBAdaptor.getProductByName(getItem(position));
```

(You also don't need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` when using methods like `ArrayAdapter#add()`. It calls `notifyDataSetChanged()` for you.)

---

If you want your adapter to use your local copy of `data` you will need to override `getCount()`, `getItem()`, `add()`, etc. to use `data`... but by the time you have corrected everything you won't be using much of ArrayAdapter any more, you may as well extend BaseAdapter.

Though it looks like you want to work with a database (`openDB()`). You should use Cursors and CursorAdapters since they are much more efficient than converting a table to an Array.